# How to create a new csv file with only modified datas?(Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I want to create a new csv file with only modified datas. The input csv file is of example as
[image]

input.csv

Now I want to create a new csv file of modified datas only like

[image: output.csv]

The condition is :

```
df1.loc[df1['Code'].astype(str).str.len() >12, 'Code']= '0'
```

What I've tried is

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df1.loc[df1['Code'].astype(str).str.len() >12, 'Code']= ''


df2 = df1.reindex(['ID','Name','Code','Changed Code'],axis=1)
```

How to create a new dataframe for modified datas in this case? Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code for select rows by condition with columns names in list and assign to new DataFrame `df2`, also you can add `dtype` parameter to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for avoid converting column `Code` to numbers (and adding scientific notation):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('input.csv', dtype={'Code':str})

#if need new column filled by 0
df1['Changed Code'] = '0'
df2 = df1.loc[df1['Code'].str.len() >12, ['ID','Name','Code','Changed Code']]
```

If converting to strings in read_csv is not necessary:

```
 df1 = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
 df2 = df1.loc[df1['Code'].astype(str).str.len() >12, ['ID','Name','Code','Changed Code']]
 df2['Changed Code'] = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('input.csv')


df2 = df1.loc[df1['Code'].astype(str).str.len() >12]
df2 = df2.reindex(['Id','Name','Code','Changed Code'],axis=1)

df2.loc[df2['Code'].astype(str).str.len() >12,'Changed Code']='0'
df2
```

Comment: your solution shows some errors because locs cannot be used in with lists somewhere like that. I took reference of selecting columns conditionally from your solution. That worked